# jQuery Datatables server side pagination with Restangular

Tags: datatables, restangular, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

How can I use server side pagination with Restangular? 
When I enable "withOption('serverSide', true)", Datatables will call the API twice: A regular call and a datatables call passing datatables values but without the route "api/clientes".

https://s31.postimg.org/xz3v7q9bf/datatables.jpg

I'm trying this code but with no success.
How can I solve this

```
var getTableData = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            RestangularAuth.all('clientes').getList().then(function (result) {
                defer.resolve(result.data);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        };


            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(getTableData())
                //.withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```